# how to retrieve values from dynamodb by lambda function

Tags: python

I need to retrieve values from dynamodb by lambda function

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['DB_TABLE_NAME'])
    postItem = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('id').eq(postId)
    )
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

Comment: Is this the actual code? Whitespace matters in `Python`, so you might need to change your indents here.

Comment: this is the actual code I am new to python coding as well .

Comment: Where is your lambda function? you need to have a lambda function in your lambda code.

Comment: You have not imported os module as well

Comment: sorry guys , It was under def lambda_handler(event, context):

Answer (score 0):

You need a lambda handler in your code and you need to import os module as well. This might get you started.

```
import boto3
import os
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    postId = event["postId"]

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['DB_TABLE_NAME'])

    if postId=="*":
        items = table.scan()
    else:
        items = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('id').eq(postId)
        )

    return items["Items"]
```

Comment: i have tried above solution  i am matching a string {
  "postId": "open"
}  , i am getting START RequestId: 8377ab44-d39c-495c-b609-88f4bcce77f5 Version: $LATEST
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: Order number : ClientError